# How can I Send and receive files with Agora SDK in android Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, agora-implementation, agora

I have an App that is doing chat messages (conversation, chatting) correctly using Agora but now I want to integrate the file attachment as well. If anyone has a code then please share it with me. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create

```
// Set fileLocalUri as the URI of the file message on the local device.
ChatMessage message = ChatMessage.createFileSendMessage(fileLocalUri, toChatUsername);
// Sets the chat type as one-to-one chat, group chat, or chatroom.
if (chatType == CHATTYPE_GROUP) message.setChatType(ChatType.GroupChat);
ChatClient.getInstance().chatManager().sendMessage(message);
```

2. Send

```
// Calls setMessageStatusCallback to set the callback instance to listen for the state of messaging sending. You can update the message states in this callback.
message.setMessageStatusCallback(new CallBack() {
    @OverRide
    public void onSuccess() {
        // Send message success
    }
    @OverRide
    public void onError(int code, String error) {
        // Send message failed
    }
});
ChatClient.getInstance().chatManager().sendMessage(message);
```

3. receive

```
CallBack callBack = new CallBack() {
    @OverRide
    public void onSuccess() {
        // Download successfully
    }
    @Override
    public void onProgress(int progress, String status) {
     // Show progress
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(int code, String error) {
     // Download failed
    }
};
// Set Callback to know whether the download is finished.
message.setMessageStatusCallback(callBack);
// Download the video.
ChatClient.getInstance().chatManager().downloadAttachment(message);

// After the download finishes, get the URI of the local file.
NormalFileMessageBody fileMessageBody = (NormalFileMessageBody) message.getBody();
// Retrieves the file from the server.
String fileRemoteUrl = fileMessageBody.getRemoteUrl();
// Retrieves the file from the local device.
Uri fileLocalUri = fileMessageBody.getLocalUri();
```

Refer to this [link](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/client-api/messages/send-receive-messages?platform=android#send-and-receive-a-file-message)